# Change RSI Plot Range - Possible or not?

Tags: range, pine-script, indicator, rsi

We know that RSI plotting range is between 0 to 100.

Is it possible to change a plotted indicator line so that it will fluctuate in an extended range, say -50 to 100 ?

In simple way I want it to be (stretched) so I can easily draw trend line on the RSI line.

Attached photo is sample of what I mean on is perfect , one that I have is not like it.

I want the the RSI to cross the green and red area without affecting the movement of the indicator. I just want it to be stretching.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJ1UL.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4Wp7.png)

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="Relative Strength Index", shorttitle="RSI", format=format.price, precision=2, timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)

ma(source, length, type) =>
    switch type
        "SMA" => ta.sma(source, length)
        "Bollinger Bands" => ta.sma(source, length)
        "EMA" => ta.ema(source, length)
        "SMMA (RMA)" => ta.rma(source, length)
        "WMA" => ta.wma(source, length)
        "VWMA" => ta.vwma(source, length)

rsiLengthInput = input.int(14, minval=1, title="RSI Length", group="RSI Settings")
rsiSourceInput = input.source(close, "Source", group="RSI Settings")
maTypeInput = input.string("SMA", title="MA Type", options=["SMA", "Bollinger Bands", "EMA", "SMMA (RMA)", "WMA", "VWMA"], group="MA Settings")
maLengthInput = input.int(50, title="MA Length", group="MA Settings")

up = ta.rma(math.max(ta.change(rsiSourceInput), 0), rsiLengthInput)
down = ta.rma(-math.min(ta.change(rsiSourceInput), 0), rsiLengthInput)
rsi = down == 0 ? 100 : up == 0 ? 0 : 100 - (100 / (1 + up / down))
rsiMA = ma(rsi, maLengthInput, maTypeInput)

rsicolor = rsi > 70 ? color.new(#ff0057, 0) : rsi < 30 ? color.new(#ff0057, 0) : #1056ee

plot(rsi, "RSI", color=rsicolor, linewidth=2, style=plot.style_stepline)
plot(rsiMA, "RSI-based MA", color=color.rgb(120, 206, 255))


OverBought1 = input.int(80, minval=1)
OverBought2 = input.int(90, minval=1)
OverSold1 = input.int(20, minval=1)
OverSold2 = input.int(10, minval=1)


OB1 = hline(OverBought1 , color=color.red, linestyle=hline.style_dashed)
OB2 = hline(OverBought2 , color=color.red, linestyle=hline.style_dashed)
OS1 = hline(OverSold1 , color=color.green, linestyle=hline.style_dashed)
OS2 = hline(OverSold2 , color=color.green, linestyle=hline.style_dashed)

fill(OB1 , OB2, color=color.rgb(255, 82, 82, 80), title="Red Zoon Fill")
fill(OS1 , OS2 , color=color.rgb(76, 175, 79, 80), title="Green Zoon Fill")
```

Any ideas, please?

Thank you!

Colin

Is it possible to change a plotted indicator line so that it will fluctuate in an extended range, say -50 to 100 ?

In simple way I want it to be (stretched) so I can easily draw trend line on the RSI line.

Attached photo is sample of what I mean on is perfect , one that I have is not like it.

I want the the RSI to cross the green and red area without affecting the movement of the indicator. I just want it to be stretching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `normalize()` [function](https://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#how-can-i-rescale-an-indicator-from-one-scale-to-another):

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")

normalize(_src, _min, _max) =>
    // Normalizes series with unknown min/max using historical min/max.
    // _src      : series to rescale.
    // _min, _min: min/max values of rescaled series.
    var _historicMin =  10e10
    var _historicMax = -10e10
    _historicMin := math.min(nz(_src, _historicMin), _historicMin)
    _historicMax := math.max(nz(_src, _historicMax), _historicMax)
    _min + (_max - _min) * (_src - _historicMin) / math.max(_historicMax - _historicMin, 10e-10)

rsi = ta.rsi(close, 20)

rsiNormalized = normalize(rsi, -50, 100)

plot(rsiNormalized)

hline(-50)
hline(100)
```

**EDIT**

In your case, since we know the scale will always be between 0 to 100, we can use math to solve the issue much more accurately:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")

rsi = ta.rsi(close, 20)    // this will give a value between 0 to 100

// find the value compared to a scale of 100
rsiPerc = rsi / 100 

// multiply by the new range to get the position of rsi on the new range
rsiOnNewScale = rsiPerc * 150

// place the newRsi on a scale of -50 to 100
newRsi = rsiOnNewScale - 50

plot(newRsi)

hline(-50)
hline(100)
```

Or in short:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")

rsi = ta.rsi(close, 20)    // this will give a value between 0 to 100

newRsi = (rsi / 100 * 150) - 50

plot(newRsi)

hline(-50)
hline(100)
```

Comment: You are super genuis mr_statler. Thank you so much for helping me. Many thanks

Comment: Thanks! I thought about a better and more accurate solution. I've edited my answer with the other solution

Comment: RSI is never over 100, so if you'll use the second more accurate solution the `newRsi` will also never be greater than 100. Let's say `rsi` is equal to the maximum value of 100, then it will be `100/100*150` which is equal to 150. Subtracting 50 from the result, will give us 100

Comment: Please I need another favour if you can. Could you add (condition) to the first solution that keep rsiNormalized = 100 if its value reach over 100 (because  I changed the setting to ( 122, -60 ). Condition couldd be like this  ( rsiNormalized > 100 ? 100 : rsiNormalized) something like that. sorry I'm begginer and I don't know how to do it. Many thanks

Comment: Just use the same logic. If you're looking for a range between 122 to -60, then use `newRsi = (rsi / 100 * 182) - 60`